# Ora-00911 Invalid Character in Oracle Query

Tags: sql, oracle, syntax-error

I've just try the following query:

```
SELECT EXAM_NUMBER, DATE_EXAM, DATE_UNIV
  FROM UNIVERSITY.C_CALENDAR cc2
 WHERE EXAM_NUMBER = 'L'
   AND LAST_FILE = 'OK'
   AND MATTER = 'MATH'
   AND STATE_CODE NOT IN ('FC')
   AND TO_CHAR(DATE_EXAM, 'YYYY-MM-DD') = TO_CHAR(SYSDATE - 2, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
   AND TO_CHAR(DATE_UNIV, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') < TO_CHAR(SYSDATE - 5, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
 ORDER BY DATE_EXAM DESC
```

I always get error

> ORA-00911: invalid character

could you help me?

Comment: Just get rid of `TO_CHAR()` conversions and their formatting masks as those columns seem to be of date type while converting `TO_CHAR(DATE_EXAM, 'YYYY-MM-DD') = TO_CHAR(SYSDATE - 2, 'YYYY-MM-DD')` to `TRUNC(DATE_EXAM) = TRUNC(SYSDATE - 2)`

Comment: [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/9choQCsx) does not show that error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query appears to be fine. You may have an invisible character in the source code (but it is not showing when I copy-paste from your question, even looking at the mark-up).

You do not need to use `TO_CHAR` when filtering (as it will prevent Oracle from using an index on the column):

```sql
SELECT EXAM_NUMBER,
       DATE_EXAM,
       DATE_UNIV
FROM   UNIVERSITY.C_CALENDAR cc2
WHERE  EXAM_NUMBER =  'L'
AND    LAST_FILE   =  'OK'
AND    MATTER      =  'MATH'
AND    STATE_CODE  != 'FC'
AND    DATE_EXAM   >= TRUNC(SYSDATE - 2)
AND    DATE_EXAM   <  TRUNC(SYSDATE - 1)
AND    DATE_UNIV   <  SYSDATE - 5
ORDER BY
       DATE_EXAM DESC
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/oa9Ta9tn)

Answer (score 0):

It looks ok when used from sql developer.
How do you use this command? In my experience that error raises if I have extra semi-colon when running the command with Execute Immediate or with some other software connected to oracle db. For instance when run from python program and the command has semi-colon at the end oracle returns:
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: **ORA-00911: invalid character**
Without semi-colon everything is ok.